# Cannot resolve method click()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an element and I want it to be clicked, but I have this message;

Cannot resolve method click()

```
List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div[2]"));
items.click();
```

I change the version of maven dependency. now, it is;

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: `items` is a list, you can't click it. Locate a single `WebElement` or use index.

Comment: Try performing `driver.findElement` instead of `driver.findElements`.

Answer (score 2):

You are performing `driver.findElements` which returns list of web elements that matches the given xpath pattern. And you cannot perform click over a list.

Try performing `driver.findElement` which returns a single element (the very first matching element) of type `WebElement`, you can now perform click method on this element.

Try this:

```
WebElement item = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div[2]"));
item.click();
```

**If you want to iterate over the elements and click each of them, try this.**

```
List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div[2]"));
for(WebElement item : items){
  item.click();
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I want to verify all elements are clickable by clicking all of them, how can I perform this?

Comment: Iterate over the list of elements in that case.

Comment: Does clicking any of these elements redirect you to a different page?